# Chrome, not rendering my jquery sldieshow locally, but loading when online (internet) (Works in FF, IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

I seemed to have tracked down the problem, but I am:

1. Not sure "why" it is happening
2. Not sure how to fix it?

Background:

I am making use of css to style my images to width = 100%, to let the browser resize the height accordingly, depending on screen size.

When debugging in Chrome, I can see the my height variable is 0... so it seems this script runs before Chrome has had time to do its thing with the image?

- When viewing online, the slideshow works perfectly fine
- The slideshow works locally AND online, using FF and IE
- As above, does not work on Chrome locally, but works when online (remote hosting)

I am worried that this issue will manifest itself online as well.. as there is obviously some condition that freaks out something... which I want to fix.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ReloadBanner();
});

function ReloadBanner() {

    var width = $(".BannerHolder div.slides div a img").width();    // Current image width
    var height = $(".BannerHolder div.slides div a img").height();  // Current image height

    $(".BannerHolder").jContent({
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        easing: "easeOutCirc",
        duration: 500,
        auto: true,
        pause_on_hover: true,
        direction: 'next',
        pause: 6000,
        height: height,
        width: width
    });

    $("div.slides").children().css('margin', '0 auto');
    $("div.slides").children().css('text-align', 'center');

}
```

Comment: chrome doesn't like file protocol when page is loaded locally without beeing deserved by a server. Don't you have any error message in chrome console? BTW, to calculate image height, image needs to be loaded, see for onload event specific to this image. Of course, once image cached, this no more apply

Comment: If you're not loading external resources from the local filesystem it might be the browser is entering different rendering modes. Does your page have a _doctype_ and pass _html_ validation?

Comment: @A.Wolff , no error messages. Except some Strict Mode warning, pointing to methods inside my videojs script used later on in the page

Comment: Just for checking purpose, could you try instead of document ready handler to use: `$(window).on('load', ReloadBanner);` And remove `$(document).ready(function () {
    ReloadBanner();
})`

Comment: @A.Wolff , actually, it was initially implemented as window load, but I changed it recently... I recall it working after that change tho... but I'll give it a spin.

Comment: @PaulS., <!DOCTYPE html> , and some W3C validation issues, but nothing relating much to the scripting.., or where its used.

Comment: @A.Wolff , $(window).load(function () { , seems to fix it, thanks... but I specifically changed it to document.ready, due to my slideshow banners stacked vertically on page load, before it gets rendered into the slideshow... the document.ready seemed to fix that. P.S. (I am a bit of a js n00b here...)

Comment: Then your issue is like you have spotted it, coming from image height. You need to use onload event of the image.

Comment: @A.Wolff , thanks. Add the answer so I can mark it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind to image onload event, e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $img = $(".BannerHolder div.slides div a img");
    $img.one('load', ReloadBanner);
    // next line is to fire onload event of image on older browser even image already cached
    if ($img[0].complete) $img.load();
});
```